# How to find the last successful run time of a Jenkins Job

Tags: python, python-3.x, jenkins

Is there a way to get the last successful run time of JENKINS job using Python?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [python-jenkins](https://pypi.org/project/python-jenkins/). There is an [example](https://python-jenkins.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html#example-3-working-with-jenkins-jobs) showing how to work with Jenkins Jobs, basically:

```
server = jenkins.Jenkins('http://jenkins.xxx.com')
last_build_number = server.get_job_info('myJob')['lastCompletedBuild']['number']
build_info = server.get_build_info('myJob', last_build_number)
duration_in_seconds = build_info['duration']
```